# Why does database dependent test fail on all but first invocation through SBT

Tags: scala, jdbc, junit, sbt

I have an JUnit 4 integration test which checks if the user running the test has access to a QA database, and this test runs fine via the JUnit plugin and the first time I invoke the tests through SBT, but all subsequent invocations through SBT fail with the stack trace below.  This means I have to disable the test in order to continuously test.

```
[error] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sybase:Tds: ...
[error]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
[error]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
[error]     at ...
```

Is this something to do with how SBT manages it's classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly load the JDBC driver class in your application before connecting.

```
Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver"); // or the driver you are using
```

JDBC drivers are required to register themselved with the `DriverManager` in a static initializer block.

More details: [Connecting to the Database](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javadata/chapter/ch04.html) in *Database Programming with JDBC and Java*.

Comment: I'm familiar with how the JDBC drivers are registered, the strange thing is that the test only fails the **second** time its run.  However explicitly loading the class does allow the test to pass, but results in a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError being thrown by some of our internal code due to a jni library being loaded in another classloader.